# clone windows without sysprep

Tags: windows-7, clone, sysprep

I have to clone a windows 7 system on a lab (I have a volume license for win OS).

The Microsoft documentation tell me to prepare the windows source pc with sysprep before 
cloning the system, but... Is sysprep essential for this purpose?

I have cloned a pc, without using sysprep, on another pc, and everything seems good.
Does this way hide me some future problems, or may it be a good way to clone my lab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside making the computer unique, it also remove the old drivers and prepare the system for a new set of hardware (if you marked "Generalize").
The uniqueness is only crucial in domain networks for the authentication to work properly, but the drivers' part is important to stand-alone computers too.

Bottom line, most of the time it'll work, but it'll retain the old and useless drivers.
I think it's better to do it properly, so you won't have any unforeseen problem.

Anyway, why not using sysprep?
You can clone just like you did, only you'll have to reactivate.

Comment: Isn't the uniqueness the "SID myth"?  Is that the same?

Comment: @johnny Yeah, you're right: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx Though Sysprep is still the only supported way for duplicating computers (domain-joined or not).